# Limit the width of flex items on hover to their initial width

Tags: css, flexbox

In the demo below, when Item 3 is hovered over, the slightly longer link in the revealed content makes Item 3 expand in width:

```css
ul, li, a {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 450px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.flex-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 0;
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.flex-item:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.flex-item ul {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-item:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

.flex-item a {
  padding: 10px;
}

.flex-item ul a {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.flex-item ul a:hover {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="flex">
    <li class="flex-item">
      <a href="#">Item 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="flex-item">
      <a href="#">Item 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="flex-item">
      <a href="#">Item 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">A little bit longer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="flex-item">
      <a href="#">Item 4</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="flex-item">
      <a href="#">Item 5</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This behaviour is undesirable and I would ideally like to restrict the longer link to the initial width of the flex item, by wrapping onto multiple lines if necessary.

I'm aware that this can be easily achieved by setting `position: absolute` on the flex item's content, but this has the unwanted side effect of taking that content outside the grey container div, meaning the black borders and grey background no longer expand when the items are hovered over:

```css
ul, li, a {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 450px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.flex-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 0;
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.flex-item:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.flex-item ul {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-item:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

.flex-item a {
  padding: 10px;
}

.flex-item ul a {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.flex-item ul a:hover {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="flex">
    <li class="flex-item">
      <a href="#">Item 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="flex-item">
      <a href="#">Item 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="flex-item">
      <a href="#">Item 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">A little bit longer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="flex-item">
      <a href="#">Item 4</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="flex-item">
      <a href="#">Item 5</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Is there a CSS-only way to get the best of both, with wrapping of the flex item content ***and*** an expanding container?

**Note 1:** There can potentially be variable numbers of parent items with differing text lengths and there must always be equal spacing between each of them. Therefore, any solution which sets all the items to equal widths is not acceptable I'm afraid.

**Note 2:** The last item in the row should not have any added white space after the text.

Also, if there's some way to achieve this layout without flexbox I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: How about `flex-basis: 0` instead of `flex-basis: auto` on the flex items?

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately that changes all the items to be of equal width, whereas I need them to be equally spaced, with potentially different initial widths.

Comment: With `flex-basis: auto` you're setting the widths to content lengths. So, naturally, the item will expand on hover to fit the length of the drop-down text.

Comment: `max-width` and grid won't work either for the same reason mentioned above.

Comment: I think, at this point, your only options are fixed widths or JS. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, you're quite right, and I can fully understand why it behaves that way. I'm just hoping there's some clever way around it. I may just have to resort to JS but I'd like to avoid that if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply solve that by using CSS [`grid-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) on the `.flex` and set the `grid-template-columns` to `repeat(5, 1fr)` this will repeat 5 equal columns and if you don't want equal columns you can specify the width of each one like `100px 120px 320px ...` but make sure that the sum of them is not greater than its parent.

### Example

```css
ul,
li,
a {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 450px;
}

.flex {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.flex-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 0;
}

.flex-item:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.flex-item ul {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: none;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.flex-item:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

.flex-item a {
  padding: 10px;
}

.flex-item ul a {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.flex-item ul a:hover {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="flex">
    <li class="flex-item">
      <a href="#">Item 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="flex-item">
      <a href="#">Item 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="flex-item">
      <a href="#">Item 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">A little bit longer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="flex-item">
      <a href="#">Item 4</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="flex-item">
      <a href="#">Item 5</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Refer to the comments in the question. OP doesn't want equal size columns. I suspect that fixed widths are not an option, either.

Comment: I mentioned it i the above description that if he doesn't want it he could just set the width manually

Comment: I think it's fair to assume that if that was an option, OP wouldn't be posting this question, as it is the simplest solution.

Comment: I tried everything like changing `flex-basis`, `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and I also payed with `max-width` and `min-width` but nothing solves it the `ul a` is still expanding on mouseover event but `grid` makes fixed columns so that there is no expansion while hovering the `ul a`

Comment: Fixed width columns are also possible with flex, using `flex-basis: 0; flex-grow: 1`. There's no clear benefit in switching to grid.

Comment: @morbiD you said  *if there's some way to achieve this layout without `flexbox` you're open to suggestions.* does my way solves your question or is there anything you want me to improve

Comment: @Gad I'm afraid your answer doesn't address either of the two notes I added to the question. Your answer requires fixed widths on the columns **and** creates extra white space after Item 5 (unless the fixed width of that item perfectly matches the text length). Sorry!